# Power View Not Working Excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

So I've manually added power view to my toolbar, but when I try to click it nothing happens. Is this a known issue? My understanding was that Excel 2016 was supposed to automatically include power views.

Answer (score 0):

go File > Options > Add-Ins > select Com Add-Ins > Go

Is the PowerView add-in checked?